# about memory address in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-smash

I'm now taking the coursera course and I have a question about one of the readings.

Link: http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

```
0x8000490 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
0x8000491 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
0x8000493 <main+3>:     subl   $0x4,%esp
0x8000496 <main+6>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x800049d <main+13>:    pushl  $0x3
0x800049f <main+15>:    pushl  $0x2
0x80004a1 <main+17>:    pushl  $0x1
0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x80004b5 <main+37>:    pushl  %eax
0x80004b6 <main+38>:    pushl  $0x80004f8
0x80004bb <main+43>:    call   0x8000378 <printf>
0x80004c0 <main+48>:    addl   $0x8,%esp
0x80004c3 <main+51>:    movl   %ebp,%esp
0x80004c5 <main+53>:    popl   %ebp
0x80004c6 <main+54>:    ret
0x80004c7 <main+55>:    nop
```

---

> We can see that when calling function() the RET will be 0x8004a8, and
>   we want to jump past the assignment at 0x80004ab.  The next
>   instruction we want to execute is the at 0x8004b2.  A little math
>   tells us the distance is 8 bytes.

As it says, what we need to do is to assign RET with the value 0x8004b2. Obviously, the distance would be 10, because 0x8004b2 minus 0x8004a8 equals 10.

How could it be 8 bytes? where am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterCordes : don't see how that applies here. 8 seems plain wrong. The add afterwards is 3 bytes, the next mov is 7 bytes. Seems like a difference of 10 decimal if you want to skip by the add and first mov to land on the second mov

Comment: @Michael Petch So I'm correct about this issue?

Comment: From my perspective if the intent is to jump to the second mov then what you say seems correct to me. Maybe I am missing something obvious. 8 bytes makes little sense to me personally.

Comment: Maybe I a m misunderstanding what they intended here. Did they want to replace the Add instruction with a JMP instruction or did the intend to modify the return address of the call to return to the beginning of the second move. I assume this was about altering the return address.

Comment: @Michael Petch here is the source code:void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n",x);
}

Comment: @Michael Petch: it intends to skip by the assignment to x and reach the next printf directly

Comment: My belief is that the article is just wrong and it should be 10.

Comment: @Michael Petch thx for your time.

Comment: While 10 (0xA) seems to be correct, it would skip the adjustment of the stack pointer after the call, which, to me, seems like a dangerous thing to do.